# how to accelerate and stop a sprite(car) using isTouched() in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I am working on Android libgdx project. I want to accelerate and stop a sprite using isTouched(). Plz help me and give me a answer with example

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tested the code but the logic should be like this:

```
float accel;
float speed;
float maxSpeed;
float maxAccel;
float maxDeceleration;

void init()
{
    accel = 0;
    speed = 0;
    maxSpeed = 300.0f; // Speed limit example
    maxAccel = 5.0f; // Acceleration limit example
    maxDeceleration = 1.0f;
}

void update()
{
    if(touching)
        accel += 0.1f;
    else
        accel -= 0.1f;

    if(accel > maxAccel)
        accel = maxAccel;

    if(speed == 0.0f && accel < 0.0f)
        accel = 0.0f;
    else if(speed > 0.0f && accel < -maxDeceleration)
        accel = -maxDeceleration;

    speed += accel;

    if(speed >= maxSpeed)
        speed = maxSpeed
    else if(speed < 0.0f)
        speed = 0.0f;
}
```